Can W3C traceparent be set by Java OpenTelemetry SDK
I am working to set the traceparent header in OpenTelemetry
https://w3c.github.io/trace-context/#traceparent-header
I am using the JAVA OTEL SDK and wanted to know if there is a Java based solution to create the traceparent through a Java function.
Thanks,
Prabal

opentelemetry-java maintainer here.
Yes. opentelemetry-java has an interface called TextMapPropagator which extracts and injects context. There's a w3c trace context implementation called W3CTraceContextPropagator which injects and extracts the w3c trace context headers traceparent and tracestate.
See ContextPropgators for a demonstration of extracting and injecting context.
See TextMapPropagators for a discussion on the different implementations available.
To manually put SpanContext into Context, do something like:
    Context context =
        Context.current()
            .with(
                Span.wrap(
                    SpanContext.create(
                        "<traceId>",
                        "<spanId>",
                        TraceFlags.getDefault(),
                        TraceState.getDefault())));

